# Quantiling values with SQLite and Python (sqlite3 package)

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table with 252 rows with a column ranging in values from 0 - 93 and want to quantile them. I'm using SQLiite, Python and sqlite3 python package to create and manipulate these tables.

What would be the best method to quantile values using SQLite and/or Python? I'd considered using RANK() but this function is not available in SQLite.

Comment: How many values? Could you load them all into a Python data structure?

Comment: 3. Python Lists is my current method but it just feels a bit messy having to add the data back into a table as it would involve creating new tables and insert into etc.